# Impersonation does not work with Google Cloud Storage service-account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-kms

We have multiple entities(compute instances, GKE pods etc. each with their unique service-account) in GCP project-1(in org-1) which need access to a KMS key residing in GCP project-2(in org-2) to encrypt/decrypt some secrets. Instead of providing `cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypterDecrypter` role to multiple service-accounts(from project-1), we're following [this](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/create-short-lived-credentials-direct#permissions-sa) guide to perform service-account impersonation (kinda similar to the assume-role functionality in AWS).

As a result, we have one service-account(`key-access-sa`) in project-1 which is granted `cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypterDecrypter` role in project-2 for the KMS key. All other service-accounts(of compute instances, GKE pods etc.) in project-1 are given `iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator` role to impersonate the "privileged" service-account `key-access-sa`. Everything works fine - compute instances can use the KMS key from project-2 ***only*** when they impersonate as `key-access-sa`.

However there is another use-case where we need ability to upload some objects(from within the compute instance) to GCS buckets that are encrypted with KMS key from project-2. Following the above doc, I used below cmd to allow the GCS default service-account in project-1 to be able to impersonate as `key-access-sa`. *Since `key-access-sa` already has access to encrypt/decrypt using KMS key, I am expecting the GCS service to be able to use that key as well*:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding key-access-sa@project-1.iam.gserviceaccount.com --member=serviceAccount:service-<accountid>@gs-project-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role=roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator
```

However when I try to upload an object to GCS bucket from within the compute VM, it fails with this error:

```
<username>@tenant-vm:~$ gsutil cp test gs://bucket1/test
Copying file://test [Content-Type=application/octet-stream]...
AccessDeniedException: 403 Permission denied on Cloud KMS key. Please ensure that your Cloud Storage service account has been authorized to use this key.
```

I've even tried `gsutil -i` cmd but it gives the same error:

```
<username>@tenant-vm:~$ gsutil -i key-access-sa@project-1.iam.gserviceaccount.com cp test gs://bucket1/test
WARNING: This command is using service account impersonation. All API calls will be executed as [key-access-sa@project-1.iam.gserviceaccount.com].
Copying file://test [Content-Type=application/octet-stream]...
AccessDeniedException: 403 Permission denied on Cloud KMS key. Please ensure that your Cloud Storage service account has been authorized to use this key.
```

It is only when I add an IAM policy binding for project-2's KMS key to attach `cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypterDecrypter` role to the default GCS service-account(from project-1) that compute instances can successfully upload/download objects to encrypted GCS buckets.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before? Is it really not possible to have the GCS service *impersonate* another "privileged" service-account to get short-lived tokens to perform a privileged action? I could not find this behaviour documented in any of the GCP public docs.

Comment: I think the feature doesn't exist, but your use case is interesting. You could open a case here and discuss with the engineering team about it https://issuetracker.google.com/issues

Comment: Raised https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/270201658, thanks @guillaumeblaquiere